# How messages get logged?

Tags: linux-kernel, logs

I want to understand how *printk* works behind the scenes, so, how Linux kernel log messages getting logged?

Comment: Your question does not precisely describe what you are waiting for. How printk works ? How kernel-only ? applications ? logs are processed to make admin aware of them ? About the former, its very simple you know... printk simply writes into a ring buffer in ram.

Answer (score 2):

What a coincidence, I just read about it in the book *Linux Device Drivers* v3.  [Chapter 4](https://static.lwn.net/images/pdf/LDD3/ch04.pdf) of that book says:

> **How Messages Get Logged**
>
> The `printk` function writes messages into a circular buffer that is `__LOG_BUF_LEN` bytes long: a value from 4 KB to 1 MB chosen while configuring the kernel. The function then wakes any process that is waiting for messages, that is, any process that is sleeping in the `syslog` system call or that is reading `/proc/kmsg`. These two interfaces to the logging engine are almost equivalent, but note that reading from `/proc/kmsg` consumes the data from the log buffer, whereas the `syslog` system call can optionally return log data while leaving it for other processes as well. In general, reading the `/proc` file is easier and is the default behavior for `klogd`. The `dmesg` command can be used to look at the content of the buffer without flushing it; actually, the command returns to `stdout` the whole content of the buffer, whether or not it has already been read.
>
> If you happen to read the kernel messages by hand, after stopping `klogd`, you’ll find that the `/proc` file looks like a FIFO, in that the reader blocks, waiting for more data. Obviously, you can’t read messages this way if `klogd` or another process is already reading the same data, because you’ll contend for it. If the circular buffer fills up, `printk` wraps around and starts adding new data to the beginning of the buffer, overwriting the oldest data. Therefore, the logging process loses the old data. ... Another feature of the Linux approach to messaging is that `printk` can be invoked from anywhere, even from an interrupt handler, with no limit on how much data can be printed. The only disadvantage is the possibility of losing some data.